# How to add changebar in latex?

Tags: latex

In Latex, I've created a new command 'changedtext' to mark specifics parts in my document and make it appear blue:

```
\newcommand{\changedtext}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1} }
```

Is there any easy way to alter the command to have change bars appear next to the text in the resulting PDF? 
If not possible, any other suggestion for a visual markup (other than change bars) that would be clear on a black & white printout would be useful as well.

**Update:** It might be of interest to readers of this question that some time ago I started using the [latexdiff](http://emeryblogger.com/2011/01/14/diff-your-latex-files-with-latexdiff/) script to mark up changes between two versions. I use it in combination with SVN, which I think works great; if you split up your LaTeX files, you might want to look at [this tex.stackexchange question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61405/latexdiff-svn-not-working-with-multiple-files-flatten/61523#61523) though.

Comment: You maybe should look at texdiff: http://mark.doll.name/texdiff/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use one of the [changebar](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=changebars) macro packages in your command.

Comment: Hmm, this solution has quite some restrictions. I've tried the changebar package, and inserted a \cbstart and \cbend in my command, by this creates problems when I use my command for example in formulas.

Answer (score 2):

One other way which would be very clear in B&W would be highlight (shows as gray background).

Use packages [`soul`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/soul/) and `color` and define your highlight color:

```
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{.92,.92,.92}
\sethlcolor{lightgray}
```

Now you can use `\hl{highlighted text}` in text to highlight.

Comment: Hadn't thought of that, nice idea !

Answer (score 0):

Some half-baked solution (not satisfactory) I just came up with myself, is the use of `\marginpar` to have some arbitrary indication in the margin, e.g.:

```
\newcommand{\changedtext}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1 \marginpar{r1}} }
```

will put the text 'r1' (from revision 1) in the margin.

However, when using this, the `\changedtext` command can not be used everywhere (e.g. in formulas, captions) because LateX will complain (in my case) about 'float(s) lost'.

Still,it might be useful to some people...